# D3 180 degree arc is only 90 degrees

Tags: svg, d3.js

I expect this code to draw a 180 degree arc. Instead I am getting a 90 degree arc.

This is essentially just a helloworld for using d3.svg.arc.

http://jsfiddle.net/L9nuX/

snippet that draws the arc:

```
var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(60)
        .outerRadius(70)
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);
```

Comment: Since a _start_ angle of PI/2 gives you the same _visible_ result … it should be easy to figure out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **does** draw a 180 degree arc, you just don't see it.

Try `.attr('transform', 'translate(100,100)')` your `speedometer` selection.

Answer (score 1):

You're arc is centered in the upper left corner, thus the "first" 90 degrees (from 12 o'clock to 3 o'clock) are out of the view.